# How can I take a file of constants, and fill certain areas with a file of multiple variables in unix?

Tags: unix, csv, awk

I have 2 files, one with just a row of constants with 3 empty fields that need to have the variables plugged into to create a file of a complete unique files.

Example:

**Constants.csv:**

> 1,,3,4,,6,7,,9,10

**Variables.csv:**

> a,b,c
>
> d,e,f
>
> g,h,i

**Outcome.csv:**

> 1,a,3,4,b,6,7,c,9,10
>
> 1,d,3,4,e,6,7,f,9,10
>
> 1,g,3,4,h,6,7,i,9,10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just with bash:

```
template=$(< Constants.csv)
template=${template//,,/,%s,}
while IFS=, read -ra values; do 
    printf "$template\n" "${values[@]}"
done < Variables.csv > Outcome.csv
cat Outcome.csv
```

```
1,a,3,4,b,6,7,c,9,10
1,d,3,4,e,6,7,f,9,10
1,g,3,4,h,6,7,i,9,10
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) program like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    OFS = FS = ","
}

NF == 10 {
    constants = $0
}

NF == 3 {
    a = $1
    b = $2
    c = $3
    $0 = constants
    $2 = a
    $5 = b
    $8 = c
    print
}
```

Which you call thus:

```
 awk -f ./outcome.awk constants.csv variables.csv > outcome.csv
```

That assumes that the format is *exactly* as you have above. A more dynamic approach would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    OFS = FS = ","
}

constants && NF {
    split($0, vars)
    last_used_var = 0
    $0 = constants
    for (f = 1; f < NF; ++f) {
        if ($f == "") {
            $f = vars[++last_used_var]
        }
    }
    print
}

constants == "" {
    constants = $0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a perl script rather quickly that splits at the commas and inserts where it finds a space.  Also you can keep an array index for your constants and use a modulus operation to keep track of the variable to be used.